# How to consolidate multiple columns based on other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset that is organized like this:

**What I have**

```
data <- tribble(~team_one, ~team_two, ~score_one, ~score_two,
                "Australia", "New Zealand", 214, 170,
                "Australia", "New Zealand", 214, 170,
                "New Zealand", "Australia", 214, 170,
                "New Zealand", "Australia", 214, 170)
```

```
team_one      team_two      score_one  score_two
Australia     New Zealand   214        170  
Australia     New Zealand   214        170  
New Zealand   Australia     214        170  
New Zealand   Australia     214        170
```

I'd like to convert that to this:

**Desired Output**

```
team          score
Australia     214           
Australia     214           
New Zealand   170           
New Zealand   170
```

I'm quite stuck on figuring out how to use what I have to get the desired output. Should I use `pivot_longer`? When I tried it, I get this, which isn't right:

**What I tried**

```
data |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("score_one", "score_two"), names_to = "name", values_to = "value")
```

```
team_one      team_two       name        value 
Australia     New Zealand   score_one   214 
Australia     New Zealand   score_two   170 
Australia     New Zealand   score_one   214 
Australia     New Zealand   score_two   170 
New Zealand   Australia     score_one   214 
New Zealand   Australia     score_two   170 
New Zealand   Australia     score_one   214 
New Zealand   Australia     score_two   170
```

Comment: Why in data does row 1 = row 2, and row 3 = row 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# I think that the values in your data have same meaning (team A:team B = team B:team A)
# So I extracted the first two rows
> data_c<-data[1:2,]

#Change the data format
> data_p<-pivot_longer(data_c, cols=everything(),
             names_to='.value',
             names_pattern='([A-Za-z]+)\\d?')

#Sort the team column in ascending order as you required
> arrange(data_p, team)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  team        score
#  <chr>       <dbl>
#1 Australia     214
#2 Australia     214
#3 New Zealand   170
#4 New Zealand   170
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe?

```
data |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = c("score_one", "score_two"), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = c("team_one", "team_two"), names_to = "t", values_to = "team") |> 
    select(team, score = value)

   team        score
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Australia     214
 2 New Zealand   214
 3 Australia     170
 4 New Zealand   170
 5 Australia     214
 6 New Zealand   214
 7 Australia     170
 8 New Zealand   170
 9 New Zealand   214
10 Australia     214
11 New Zealand   170
12 Australia     170
13 New Zealand   214
14 Australia     214
15 New Zealand   170
16 Australia     170
```

Alternatively one could also divide, rename and then rejoin.

```
one = data |> 
    select(ends_with("one")) |> 
    rename_with(~ gsub("_one", "", .x))

two = data |>
    select(ends_with("two")) |> 
    rename_with(~ gsub("_two", "", .x))

bind_rows(one, two)
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume the following:

- 4 games
- should lead to a desired table of 8 rows

I have introduced an *ID* for each game.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  # one id per game
  rowid_to_column('id') %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, score_one, score_two), names_to='Team', values_to='team') %>% 
  # get the score from either the first or second team
  mutate(score = ifelse(str_detect(Team,'_one'), score_one, score_two)) %>% 
  select(team, score)
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `id`
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>      id team        score
#>   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1     1 Australia     214
#> 2     1 New Zealand   170
#> 3     2 Australia     214
#> 4     2 New Zealand   170
#> 5     3 New Zealand   214
#> 6     3 Australia     170
#> 7     4 New Zealand   214
#> 8     4 Australia     170
```